# Server at 10.70.152.26:27017 reports maximum wire version 4, but this version of the Node.js Driver requires at least 6 (MongoDB 3.6)

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-compass

When I connect to mongodb using a url, I get the error:

> Server at 10.70.152.26:27017 reports maximum wire version 4, but this
> version of the Node.js Driver requires at least

[image: screenshot of mongodb compass showing error] 6 (MongoDB 3.6)

Answer (score 9):

Try to download an older version of Mongodb compass. like 1.28.4
here is the link to it [Mongo 1.28.4](https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass-1.28.4-win32-x64.msi).

and Try checking your admin username and see if you have the correct access or not. hope this helps

Comment: You also need to disable automatic updates in the settings of MongoDB Compass, otherwise it will automatically update itself to the latest version.

Comment: Nice! I am running a legacy app that uses MongoDB 3.4 inside WSL2 and the latest version of compass (1.35.0 ) was throwing the wire version error. Version 1.28.4 works perfect using mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017 from Windows into WSL2. Sweet!

Comment: Why not update everything, downgrading sure works but if we down grade ever thing we had issues would still be using DOS.

Comment: For MacOS: https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass-1.28.4-darwin-x64.dmg

Answer (score 1):

You are using a server which only support protocol version 4 and a client which requires at least protocol version 6. You need to either use a driver which supports protocol version 4 or a server which supports protocol version 6.

Comment: please guide me to fix this sir

Comment: Upgrade compass

Comment: can you give me link or something to guide me how i upgrade my compass sir please

Comment: @SukmaWijaya: Asking for links is off-topic. That is what Google is for.